# Docker installation for running node and react environment

Tags: reactjs, express, docker

i am facing following error while installing docker

Service 'webpack' failed to build: failed to register layer: open /var/lib/docker/aufs/layers/7e80462cf605c738f8d502a5d2707a4e4a7fb03daad65d0113240d9f1428df0f: no such file or directory

```js
version: "2"
services:

  webpack:
    image : express-react-image
    build: .
    command: ./bin/webpack-dev
    volumes:
      - .:/src/app
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=localhost
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - front_tier
  server:
    build: .
    command: ./bin/start-web
    volumes:
      - .:/src/app
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=localhost
      - APP_HOST=http://localhost:3000
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - front_tier
volumes:
  data:
    driver: local
networks:
  front_tier:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you're seeing, `failed to register layer`, means that Docker is failing while building an image because it can't find a cached layer it expects to. The easiest way to resolve this is probably to remove all your cached layers and start the build from scratch. `docker-compose rm` Might do the trick. If not, I'd start removing containers with `docker rm` and images with `docker rmi` 'til you've got a clean enough slate that it works.

If manual cleanup is slow/hard, you might have better luck with `docker system prune`.

Regardless of you you get your cached layers cleaned up, I'd expect that to work with a fresh `docker-compose up`.

Comment: my docker build currectly, but when i open any browser doesnt work in my local pc. i have used this startup kit https://github.com/developertown/docker-react-express-starter-kit

Comment: i am new in docker setup. i need react redux express and mysql setup so plz can you help me.? thanks.